# How to display link of video url in details menu?

Tags: magento-2.1

This is seriously basic but I'm having trouble to achieve it.
I need to add some link inside the menu details as you can see in the following image:

[image]

There are : 

 `- Loose fit 
 - Refectivity 
 - ect...I need to add some link here like videos of youtube or some other link.`

I want to create this link in a new column in the table like `video_url`. so that all product can have this field.

I'm using **magento 2.1** fresh installation, with sample data.

Hopefully someone can explain step by step to do this. **Programmatically**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Product details content is added to product from admin. To change or add  Go to **Products->Catalog** in admin panel. Then edit the product you want to add links, on edit page you can find product description field , you can add your links there for particular product.

Comment: can we do this programmatically ? sorry I didn't ask in my question, updating now

Comment: yes you can do it programmatically,  check this question to update product programmatically https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156087/how-to-correctly-update-product-programmatically-magento-2